# Using CLGeocoder to find the nearest city

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, clgeocoder

So I've been looking at this for a while, and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I am trying to use `CLGeocoder` in an iOS app to find the nearest city to where the user long taps on the map. I have two main problems:

1. Even if the user is very zoomed out, and the user taps on say New York (which is what they intend), because of how zoomed out the map is, `CLGeocoder` often returns a nearby city instead of the more obvious answer of New York. I can't work out how to set the "fuzziness" of the search to overcome this issue.
2. In many instances the `City` field is null in the returned placemark object, most commonly in remote areas such as deserts or oceans. In this case, I would ideally want to find the nearest object that actually has `City` defined, but can't work out how to do this.

Comment: To clarify, I've done some more testing, and it seems neither Apple Maps or Google Maps for iOS overcome this issue. Both will give street specific addresses for dropped pins, even when zoomed out so far that you can't possibly be targeting a street.

Answer (score 0):

For Get all Detail of your Location by using `CLGeocoder`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [currentLocation stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeValue longitude:longitudeValue];


    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks)
            {
                NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
                NSLog(@"placemark.country %@",placemark.country);
                NSLog(@"placemark.postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);
                NSLog(@"placemark.administrativeArea %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
                NSLog(@"placemark.locality %@",placemark.locality);
                NSLog(@"placemark.subLocality %@",placemark.subLocality);
                NSLog(@"placemark.subThoroughfare %@",placemark.subThoroughfare);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failed getting city: %@", [error description]);
        }

    }];


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you've misunderstood my question. I have CLGeocoder working well, I am just wondering how to manage locating the nearest city, rather than a town or precinct.